# Adding event listener makes content disappear

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an etch-a-sketch page. The idea is to generate a grid where each square takes a random color each time you mouse over it. However when I add an event listener to the squares, the grid appears for a few milliseconds then disappears. Without the event listener the grid appears just fine, without changing color. Here is my JavaScript function:

```js
function makeGrid() {

  const etch = document.getElementById("etchSpace");

  etch.innerHTML = "";

  const size = document.getElementById("inputField").value;

  const x = 550 / size;

  for (let i = 1; i <= size; i++) {;
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    row.setAttribute("style", "display: flex; flex-direction: row; border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 550px");
    row.style.height = x + "px";
    row.id = "row" + i;

    document.getElementById("etchSpace").appendChild(row);

    for (let j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
      let columnPiece = document.createElement("div");
      columnPiece.setAttribute("style", "border-right: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid black; background-color: lightgrey");
      columnPiece.style.height = x + "px";
      columnPiece.style.width = x + "px";
      columnPiece.id = "column" + i + j;

      document.getElementById("row" + i).appendChild(columnPiece);
    }
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
      let element = document.getElementById("column" + i + j);

      element.addEventListener("mouseover", "element.style.background = random_rgba()");
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">Grid size (max. 64):</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputField" name="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Generate" id="generateButton" onclick="return makeGrid();">
</form>
```

The following *for* breaks my code:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= size; i++)
{
    for(let j = 1; j <= size; j++)
    {
        let element = document.getElementById("column" + i + j);

        element.addEventListener("mouseover", "element.style.background = random_rgba()");
    }
}
```

The following is the html form from which I get the grid's size:

```
<form>
  <label for="fname">Grid size (max. 64):</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputField" name="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Generate" id = "generateButton" onclick = "return makeGrid();">
</form>
```

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but you have an extra semicolon here: 
```const x = 550 / size;

for(let i = 1; i <= size; i++)
{;
```

Comment: Note that the code given does not replicate the problem described, since the button is a submit button and the code throws an error before reaching the `return false;` line.

Comment: `element.addEventListener("mouseover", "element.style.background = random_rgba()");` <= why are you giving a string as the callback, rather than an actual callback?

Comment: Note that because you are not delimiting `i` and `j` in your id, the ids for when `i` is 11 and `j` is 1 is the same as the id for when `i` is 1 and `j` is 11. Thus you have multiple ids with the same value, which is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created this codepen for your code: https://codepen.io/geuis/pen/wvMPoJa

Issue is in the 2nd line in your function:

```
  const etch = document.getElementById("etchSpace");
  etch.innerHTML = "";
```

There's no element with an id of `#etchSpace`.

Pull up the dev tools in the browser and look at the console. It will show you the errors in your code.